# SqlCeParameter null

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I have a dynamic method to insert SQL. When I put a null or empty value on parameter, my `ExecuteNonQuery()` fails... How to adjust it ?

I'm using SQL Server Compact Edition:

```
public static void SqlInsert(string table, Dictionary<string, object> values)
{
        using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionStringDestino))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var equals = new List<string>();
            var columns = new List<string>();
            var parameters = new List<SqlCeParameter>();
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var item in values)
            {
                var pn = "@sp" + i;
                columns.Add(string.Format(item.Key));
                equals.Add(string.Format("{0}", pn));
                parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter(pn, item.Value));
                i++;
            }

            string command = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2}) ", table, string.Join(", ", columns.ToArray()), string.Join(", ", equals.ToArray()));

            var sqlcommand = new SqlCeCommand(command, conn);
            sqlcommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
            sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

Comment: Are the columns null-able? What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: My column accepts null values.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @sp11 :  - Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass DBNull.Value instead of null.

```
parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter(pn, item.Value ?? DBNull.Value));
```

Comment: I tried to pass  parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter(pn, item.Value ?? DBNull.Value)); No work for me...

Comment: @Pedro: "No work for me" doesn't describe the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was going through a string object to the values...

Wrong code `dictionary.Add(column.ToString(), row[column].ToString());`

Correct `dictionary.Add(column.ToString(), row[column]);`

Thanks.